# Manually trigger an Amazon S3 Inventory Report

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Is there any way to manually kick off an Amazon S3 Inventory report job?

I'm working on a project that creates daily inventory reports to another account but I can't seem to find a way to manually kick off the run. We're in the design / development phase of a data telemetry project and are tweaking our inventory configurations but having to wait for the daily job to run to see if the configuration satisfies our requirements is really inconvenient and slowing us down.

Is there a way to manually kick off an inventory report run after making a configuration change? I've tried looking in the api documentation as well as the boto3 documentation and all I have found is a call to create a bucket inventory configuration but nothing to actually perform a run.

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know the inventory report does not run on-demand. It's quite a heavy operation for AWS for many buckets have billions of objects, so I can understand why they don't provide that service for free.

The aws cli can be used of course to get an inventory but it's incredibly slow (takes HOURS if not days just to list all objects in a bucket of a few million objects). Basically the only real options for large buckets is custom scripting with parallel execution. There are quite some open source projects out there that do this.

But since your original question is about the inventory report itself I'm afraid there is no real alternative.

Answer (score 1):

AWS S3 bucket inventory reports cannot be manually triggered. They are configured to run on a schedule. Once you set up the inventory configuration for an S3 bucket, AWS automatically generates the inventory report based on the specified schedule.